# How to fill in missing values in a table

Tags: external, create-table, oracle11gr2

```
CREATE TABLE "ORDER_LINE" 
(   
"ORDER_ID" NUMBER, 

"PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER, 

"QUANTITY" NUMBER, 

"PRICE" NUMBER, 

"PROD_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 

"PROD_ALIAS" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 

 CONSTRAINT "OL_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ORDER_ID", "PRODUCT_ID")

 CONSTRAINT "PROD_ORDER_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("PRODUCT_ID")
 REFERENCES "PRODUCT" ("PROD_CODE") 
)
```

Data in this table comes from an external table and there are some missing values in the data.

Eg: (1 (order_id),'No Id', 2 (quantity), 100 (price),'No Name ', MW (alias))

There are two missing values (prod_id, prod_name). These values are present in the PRODUCT table. This way there might be the price missing some values and the alias missing in some.

How can I get the missing values from the PRODUCT table and then insert the data into the ORDER_LINE table?

There are two keys in the PRODUCT table (product_id, product_alias). Product_id is the chosen primary key.

I suppose I have to write a procedure to fill in the missing values and insert it into order lines. But how? help!